# What meanings does "oncoming car" have?

Tags: meaning

Does "oncoming car" have three meanings?:

If we are moving by car, "*oncoming car*" can mean two variants:
**(1)** a car in front of us that's moving to us (i.e. that's moving in the opposite direction)
**(2)** a car behind us that's moving to us at the speed greater than ours (i.e. that's moving in the same direction)

If we are standing, "*oncoming car*" can mean one variant:
**(3)** every car that's moving to us

Am I right?
If not, then why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has *one* meaning - approaching from in front (whether the viewer is stationary or moving).